# Android PopupWindow inside fragment with actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using a `PopupWindow` to show some data when a user clicks a button on the action bar (using ABS). I'm also using an translate animation to show and hide the `PopupWindow` so it drops down from the top.

The behavior I want is for the action bar to always remain on top of (Bring to front - like) everything else in the activity. But when I show the `PopupWindow` the animation shows it coming down and overlapping the action bar as it travels. If I set a different height for the `PopupWindow` it also overlaps the action bar.

Is there a way to use ActionBarSherlock to always show the action bar on top of everything else including popups and dialogs? Or is there some way to attach the `PopupWindow` to the underlying fragment inside the root `FrameLayout`?

Comment: It's a custom layout that shows a `ListView` with data and images.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your view in hierarchy viewer. The hierarchy here, including where ABS is, acts as the z-index for layers of views and view groups. You could grab a layer that is under the action bar and add a custom view to it:

```
    // Grab android.R.id.content's parent to encompass the actionbar & user content
    content = ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent());

    // Make sure we inflate our menu resource before it is used
    if (dialog == null)
        dialog = (ViewGroup) <INFLATE SOME DIALOG/VIEWGROUP HERE>;

    // We need this to add a view beneath the action bar
    FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout) content.getParent();
    // There needs to be some layout params set for visibility
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP);
    // A little tricky... using negative margins can do an initial translation that hides a view
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, -(heightOfDialog), 0, 0);
    dialog.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    parent.addView(dialog, 0);
```

This should allow you to position a view beneath the dialog, and still be able to animate it how you would like using a class like TranslateAnimation:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(leftOfContent, 0, 0, 0);
animation.setDuration(TIME_TO_AUTO_SCROLL);
dialog.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: So this solution would be removing the `PopupWindow` and replacing it with a view you can put into the FrameLayout? I liked the `setAnimationStyle()` part of the PopupWindow so then I'll just have to figure out how to animate the view in and out.

Comment: I added a starting point for animations. They're pretty slick.

Comment: Awesome thanks. So how would I time the `parent.addView(...)` and the `dialog.startAnimation(...)`? If I add the view, I would think that it shows up at it's final location, which is where I want to animate it to from off the top of the screen.

Comment: I edited the answer again, adding a line to set margins. By setting negative margins, it will begin outside the area of view. This acts as an initial translation.